# Comparing list elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I make a simple code:

```
arr =  [4, 9, 5, 3, 2, 10]
kpmp = [] # Empty list to store the comparison

for i in arr:
    if i>0:
        x = 0
        j = i
        while j>=0:
            j-=1
            if arr[i] > arr[j]:
                x+=1
    kpmp.append(x)
print(kpmp)
```

But, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 11, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Which is this line `if arr[i] > arr[j]:`

The expected output I'd like to print is a list `[0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0]`
Explanation:
`arr = [4, 9, 5, 3, 2, 10]`
1. 4 has nothing to compare so the result is 0
2. 9 > 4 the result is 0
3. 4 < 5 < 9 the result is 1
4. 3 < 4 < 5 < 9 the result is 3
5. 2 < 3 < 4 < 5 < 9 the result is 4
6. Well, 10 is the greatest in the list so the result is 0

I got stuck here, kinda basic knowledge with Python, though.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are currently using elements of list as indices, which will cause an out of range error if they are greater than the length of your list.

Since `arr` contains `9`, this will throw an out of range error.  Also, you need to define `x` before your `if` statement, or else you will get a `variable not found` error.

Here is a different solution to your problem using a list comprehension and **`slicing`**:

```
x = [4, 9, 5, 3, 2, 10]
final = [sum(k > j for k in x[:i]) for i, j in enumerate(x)]

# [0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0]
```

Explanation:

```
sum(k > j for k in x[:i])
```

This counts all previous values that are greater than the current value.  `x[:i]` gets all elements before the current element in your list.

Comment: Happy to help.  I would still recommend looking at the first couple comments in my answer, and trying to get your original attempt to work.  You were close apart from a couple minor issues, and you will definitely learn more that way!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to use `i` and `j` as indices, but they will instead be the elements of the list itself. If you want use indices you have a couple of options:

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
```

or

```
for i, _ in enumerate(arr):
```

The mistake is evident if you try to print the `i` in your original code

```
arr =  [4, 9, 5, 3, 2, 10]
for i in arr:
    print(i)
```

This will print all elements of the list, each on their own line

```
4
9
5
3
2
10
```

Answer (score 2):

For fixing the above code:

- First you will need to iterate through range of length of list.
- And other change is moving statement of decreasing of `j` after comparison rather than before.

You can try as below:

```
arr =  [4, 9, 5, 3, 2, 10]
kpmp = [] # Empty list to store the comparison
# iterate through length of arr
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if i>0:
        x = 0
        j = i
        while j>=0:
            if arr[i] < arr[j]:
                x+=1
            j-=1 # decrease j after comparison rather than before

    kpmp.append(x)
print(kpmp)
```

Result:

```
[0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0]
```

## Using list comprehension:

You can also try using `list comprehension` as below:

```
kmpp = [sum(arr[i] < arr[j] for j in range(i)) for i in range(len(arr))]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in your code

```
for i in arr:
     print(i)         # will print  4 9 5 3 2 10
```

This will put every element in arr.

So arr[9] will throw an error as the array size is 6.